# set cronjob time

Tags: cron

i was trying to make a code to automatically send mails from a server. I want it to run a php everytime at every hour and 15 minutes and 30 minutes.

```
Example at 08:15, 08:30, 09:15, 09:30, etc..
```

Thank you,
Daniel!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
15-30/15 * * * * * php foo.php
```

Obviously, replace `php foo.php` with the command you'd like to run. The `15-30/15` syntax indicates: minutes 15 through 30, with increments of 15. This will make your job run every hour at xx:15 and xx:30.